# Issue in typescript - Property in type is not assignable to the same property in base type

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a generic interface defined as

```
export interface EventInput {
    eventName: string;
    metadata?: Record<string, string>;
    payload?: Record<string, unknown>;
}
```

and I create a class

```
import {EventInput, EventUtilsService} from "@learnapp-co/la-event-utils";

import {UpdateOrganisationInterface} from "./interface";

export interface OrganisationUpdatedPayload {
  orgId: string;
  pii: string;
}

export class OrganisationUpdatedEventInput implements EventInput {
  private readonly eventName = 'OrganisationUpdated';

  private readonly payload: OrganisationUpdatedPayload;

  constructor(orgId: string, body: UpdateOrganisationInterface, secret: string) {
    this.payload = {
      orgId,
      pii:  EventUtilsService.encryptPIIData({
        organisationName: body.name,
        bank: body.bank,
        ...(body.revenuePercentage && { revenuePercentage: body.revenuePercentage}),
      }, secret),
    }
  }

  public get getEventName(): string {
    return  this.eventName
  }

  public  get getPayload(): OrganisationUpdatedPayload {
    return this.payload
  }
}
```

But I am getting the error

```
TS2416: Property 'payload' in type 'OrganisationUpdatedEventInput' is not assignable to 
the same property in base type 'EventInput'.   Type 'OrganisationUpdatedPayload' is not 
assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'. Index signature is missing in type 
'OrganisationUpdatedPayload'.
```

NOTE: - There can be as many classes as possible for eg `OrganisationCreatedeventInput` with a different `payload` which will extend `EventInput` class.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Try `payload?: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>;` or `payload?: {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stating that `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput` must implement `EventInput` that has a `payload` property with a broad type.

Then you declare a different (narrowed) type directly on `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput`. This is not allowed as you can see in your error.

Typescript is telling you that you either need to narrow down the `payload` property on `EventInput` or allow this broader type in `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput`.

I would suggest that you either use generics: `interface EventInput<T>` as mentioned by @Yurii Panasenko:

Or use the broader type in `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput` and narrow it down in the getter `getPayload` with a safety check to make sure it's the correct type.

Also you're declaring properties in `EventInput` interface as public (as interfaces do) and then declare them private in `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput`. This is also not supported by TypeScript and doesn't really make sense.

If you want to do things this way, it may be better to just use inheritance. Make a base class `EventInput` and extend `OrganisationUpdatedEventInput` from this class. Something like this:

```
export abstract class EventInput<T> {
    protected abstract readonly eventName: string;
    protected readonly payload?: T;
    protected metadata?: Record<string, string>;

    constructor(payLoad?: T) {
        this.payload = payLoad;
    }

}

export interface OrganisationUpdatedPayload {
    orgId: string;
    pii: string;
}

export class OrganisationUpdatedEventInput extends EventInput<OrganisationUpdatedPayload> {
    protected readonly eventName = 'OrganisationUpdated';

    constructor(orgId: string, pii: string) {
        super({ orgId, pii });
    }

    public get getEventName(): string {
        return this.eventName;
    }

    public get getPayload(): OrganisationUpdatedPayload | undefined {
        return this.payload;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use T parameter

```
export interface EventInput<T> {
    eventName: string;
    metadata?: Record<string, string>;
    payload?:  T;
}

export class OrganisationUpdatedEventInput implements EventInput<OrganisationUpdatedPayload> {
  private readonly eventName = 'OrganisationUpdated';

  private readonly payload: OrganisationUpdatedPayload;

  constructor(orgId: string, body: UpdateOrganisationInterface, secret: string) {
    this.payload = {
      orgId,
      pii:  EventUtilsService.encryptPIIData({
        organisationName: body.name,
        bank: body.bank,
        ...(body.revenuePercentage && { revenuePercentage: body.revenuePercentage}),
      }, secret),
    }
  }

  public get getEventName(): string {
    return  this.eventName
  }

  public  get getPayload(): OrganisationUpdatedPayload {
    return this.payload
  }
}
```